# Symfony2 adminPage

Tags: php, symfony

I'm facing a problem and after a research I can't find the issue so I need your help.
I have 2 tables that are related:

media: id, path, alt

article: id, image_id, title, description

I have generated a CRUD for admin page, everything is working well; But when I click on edit in adminPage and after editing one item, I can't open the front page. I've got an error:

Impossible to access an attribute ("path") on a integer variable ("1")

I'm using Symfony2

EDIT:

I generated the Article CRUD

Article Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Nata\NataBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Nata\NataBundle\Entity\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Nata\NataBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }




    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param \Nata\NataBundle\Entity\Media $image
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setImage(\Nata\NataBundle\Entity\Media $image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return \Nata\NataBundle\Entity\Media 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }   
}
```

Media Entity:

```
<?php
namespace Nata\NataBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Media
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Nata\NataBundle\Entity\MediaRepository")
 */
class Media
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="alt", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $alt;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * Set alt
     *
     * @param string $alt
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setAlt($alt)
    {
        $this->alt = $alt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get alt
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAlt()
    {
        return $this->alt;
    }

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->path;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have __toString() on media entity ?

Comment: yes I added :  public function __toString(){return $this->path;}

Comment: Could you put both entities please. And which CRUD have you done ?